# Skip the current loop iteration when memroy usage is too much

Tags: python, memory, concurrency, operating-system

In a loop, I am running a program that may require too much memory. I want to skip the current iteration and run the next. My plan is to create a thread to monitor the memory usage. When the memory usage is too much, I can skip the iteration.

The pseudo code looks like

```
def checkMemory():
    amount
    while True:
        process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        memoryUsage = process.memory_info().rss #in bytes
        if memoryUsage > amount:
            os._exit(0)
main()
    for i in range(5):
        threading.Thread(name="Memory Regulator", target=checkMemory).start()
        large_mem_program(params[i]) #different parameters lead to different memory consumption
```

However, when `checkMemory` runs `os._exit(0)`, `main` also exits. What should I do so that when the memory usage is too much, I can just skip the current loop iteration? For instance, if `large_mem_program(params[i])` takes too much memory, then I skip it and run `large_mem_program(params[i+1])`?

Comment: @Matiiss I am sorry I cannot understand. If I just use `break` in `checkMemory`, then `large_mem_program(params[I])` is still running, and I cannot go to  `large_mem_program(params[i+1])`.  Meanwhile, I do not know how to use the flag from the thread. The thread of `checkMemory` runs parallel with `main`. I do not know how to break the `for` loop after receiving the flag from `checkMemory`.

Comment: right, well you need to put `large_mem_program` in the other thread and before starting it, get that thread's id, then run your `checkMemory` and pass the pid to it as an argument, then check for memory usage and if needed kill that process, then it should continue with the next iteration

Comment: @Matiiss Thanks! I understand now